# Python / Django - creating a photo gallery - get pics' names instead of pics themself

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following issue as a result of the lack of experience: I don't get photos in the gallery page.

The main idea is to create a pretty simple photo gallery (with Bootstrap in future). I know there are a couple of useful libraries for this purpose (like prologue, imagekit etc.), but I have a great will to understand everything from the very beginning. That is why I would like to use only Django.

As a result of all of my efforts I get the following (getting photos' names instead of photos themself):

[image]

Now I have the next:

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_in_dev', 'media_root')
```

models.py

```
class GalleryCupsModel(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cups/%Y/%m/%d')
```

admin.py

```
class GalleryCupsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['photo']

admin.site.register(GalleryCupsModel, GalleryCupsAdmin)
```

Also I uploaded 3 images via admin panel (file1, file2, file3, names of which you could see in the first figure).

view.py

```
def cups(request):
    context = {
        'context_cups': GalleryCupsModel.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'cups.html', context)
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^cups/all/$", "gallery_cups.views.cups", name="cups"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

cups.html

```
...
{% for cup in context_cups %}
   {{ cup.photo }}
{% endfor %}
...
```

Here is my folder tree:

```
├── gallery_cups
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   └── __pycache__
├── LC
│   └── __pycache__
├── static_in_dev
│   ├── media
│   ├── media_root
│   ├── my_static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   └── static_root
│       ├── admin
│       │   ├── css
│       │   ├── fonts
│       │   ├── img
│       │   │   └── gis
│       │   └── js
│       │       ├── admin
│       │       └── vendor
│       │           ├── jquery
│       │           └── xregexp
│       ├── css
│       ├── img
│       │   ├── header
│       │   └── portfolio
│       └── js
└── templates
```

**The problem is** I get the result which one can see in the very first figure instead of getting real photos. Looks like I miss smth very crucial. I just can not get what exactly do I miss.

P.S. Also I do not see files, which where uploaded in the admin panel, in the static_in_dev/media/cups. Looks like I don't adequately understand how does the MEDIA works..

P.P.S. Maybe all my efforts are just a monkey job?) And using already existing libraries is better choice in learning Django?

Comment: Message by Shang Wang was somehow useful. Now I don't get images' names, but get smth like 24 x 24 pixels images which mean "No image found".

Answer (score 1):

To render a `ImageField` into template, you need:

```
<img src="{{ cup.photo }}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that works in some way but Instead of pics I get 3 squres (like a place for the picture which is not available or deleted). Maybe there some problems with media?

Comment: Your image have a 404 response, meaning they are not found. Are you able to see the images in your file directory? Can you check the page source and see what path do those photos have?

Comment: No, I can't see uploaded via admin panel images in the file directory and can't understand, why?) Maybe, I miss smth with MEDIA_URL or MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: Your `MEDIA_ROOT` is under `BASE_ROOT/static_in_dev/media_root`. Can you check in that place?

Comment: Also check django doc about url definition for static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Well, media_root is empty as well. As for your second message, I have just updated my message here with url.py. It is exactly the same as written in that link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101816/discussion-between-moveton-and-shang-wang).

Comment: This might help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/faq/usage/#how-do-i-use-image-and-file-fields

Answer (score 0):

Well, everything was absolutely easy. You have to wrap with the for-loop not only the `<img src="{{ cup.photo.url }}" />`, but the divs' as well. See below:

```
<div class="container-float">
    <div class="row">
        {% for cup in context_cups %}
        <div id="image-{{cup.id}}" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img src="{{ cup.photo.url }}" />
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
     </div>
</div>
```